# How do you find the equivalent resistance for the following question?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

In the given circuit, i need to find the current flowing in the circuit when the switch is closed and for this i need to calculate the equivalent resistance between the terminals of the cell. **How would you calculate the equivalent resistance between the terminals of the cell?**

I calculated the equivalent resistance to be by taking 6 ohms and 3 ohms resistors in parallel and the equivalent resistance of these two in series with the 10 ohms resistor. The equivalent resistance between the terminals of the cell comes out to be 2 ohms and the current hence comes out to be 5/6 A which is not present in the options. (The options are-:2 A, 1 A, 3 A and 0 A.)

Comment: There is something wrong with your series calculation.  Also, think carefully about what the switch does.

Comment: @PeterBennett Oh i meant 5/6 ohms.

Comment: Current is not measured in Ohms.  You still seem to have a problem with claculating resistors in series.

Comment: @PeterBennett I meant that the equivalent resistance is 12 ohms and the current is 5/6 A. Sorry for that.

Comment: Actually, if the switch is open, your calculation will be correct. But the question you ask involves  **closed** switch. As @PeterBennett said, think how the closed switch affects the current flow in the circuit

Comment: @Naz If the switch is open will any current flow through the circuit?

Comment: Current will flow whether the switch is open or closed, but think about how the circuit changes when you close the switch.

Comment: @PeterBennett The last 3 wires are in parallel. Right? When the switch is open there will be no current through the last branch but when the switch is closed, the negligible resistance in the last wire makes the terminals of the 3 parallel wires equi-potent and hence there will be no current through them. Right?

Comment: Not quite, but you're getting there.  The switch and the 3 and 6 ohm resistors are all in parallel.  With the switch closed, the effective resistance of those three parallel components is Zero, as you say. What then is the total resistance of the whole circuit?  And the current through the circuit?

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes, I meant the same. The equivalent resistance comes out to be 10 ohms and the current comes out to be 1 A(     10 volts/10 ohms) but what do you think of what i said about when the switch is open?

Comment: With the switch open,  there is no current through the switch, so it has no effect on the circuit.  In that case, you have the 6 and 3 ohm resistors in parallel, for an equivalent resistance of 2 Ohms.  That is in series with the 10 Ohm, for a total circuit resistance of 12 Ohms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the switch is shorted there's no current through the 6 Ohm and the 3 Ohm resistors so the current value would be 10/10=1A.

Comment: On this sort of question, I try to give clues that will help the poster find answer, rather than just giving him the answer.

Comment: Exactly. The question asked 'how do you find ...?', not 'what is...?'